# Azure service to query Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-webjobs

Suggest any azure service which

1. can connect customer azure active directory
2. can query customer azure active directory
3. keep my application azure active directory in sync with any future change (add/remove user) on customer azure active directory ?

Comment: `Microsoft Graph API` https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph can help you query Azure AD.. I don't understand your question about sync changes between your and customer Azure AD.. try to elaborate further and also mention what you've tried so far in terms of code or approach if possible..

Comment: Requirement is to identifying right azure service to keep two Azure active directories in sync. One is our customer azure active directory and another is my application related azure active directory.  Where any future changes on customer azure active directory will have to reflect in my application related azure active directory in order to be in sync with customer azure active directory. Right we are in investigation phase, POC will be started once identified efficient/right azure service.

Comment: I'm not aware of any service that will do such a sync for you.. you may need to write something custom that uses Microsoft Graph API to figure out information and then does a sync.. Microsoft Graph also supports some Delta queries that could help identify incremental changes.. on a side note I would question the requriement itself, but that's a different topic and you're the best judge ont that..

Comment: " you may need to write something custom that uses Microsoft Graph API to figure out information and then does a sync."  Can it be webjob or Azure function or something else ? which would be more suitable azure component to do query & sync up 2 azure active directories? How custom component what I going to write will know or notified about latest changes in customer azure active directory? to pick latest changes & sync up my active directory, polling wont be feasible as there will be delay in sync up. What authentication would be required to query customer azure active directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Service to connect/query Azure AD** : [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph) can help you query Azure AD

**Sync changes between two different Azure AD tenants**: AFAIK there isn't any service that will do this for you, you need to write something custom yourself that can make use of Microsoft Graph API

**Notification on changes**: Microsoft Graph API supports change notifications for some scenarios.. User and Group resource types are supported.. see if this covers what you're looking for Use the [Microsoft Graph API to get change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0)

**Incremental changes**: Microsoft Graph API also supports delta queries for some operations, which could help in figuring out incremental changes.

**Authentication**: Most probably client credentials grant flow using Application permissions, with a daemon app would make sense for such scenario. Although, this is something you'll need to decide based on how you finally implement.

**Permissions required**: [Microsoft Graph API permissions reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference)

**Function or WebJob or something else**: it's a little subjective I guess. I don't have a clear single recommendation. WebJob might be better if it turns out to be long running, but I'm not sure. You may need a separate question or find some already answered good questions about this.

Answer (score 0):

In response to Rohit's answer: -

I agree there **isn't any Microsoft service** as of now that sync changes between two different Azure AD tenants.

Not here to brag or promote but to give a direction, the company where I work has a product which solves exactly this problem and we have few customers who are using it to keep their partner tenants in sync. In case you are looking for a pre-made product feel free to reach out to me.

Other wise if you need any help on creating your own then what Rohit mentioned are quite good steps to follow, if you still need help with that direction let me know.